# How to transform a general polynomial function into a multilinear function?

Tags: polynomials, multilinear-algebra

Is there any theorem about this question? I have found the book "Analysis of Boolean function" which introduces a "Fourier expansion" :functions as multilinear polynomials. I think this may help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaizq.png)

Comment: Have you tried googling "Fourier expansion"?

Comment: Is there a connection with the fact that any boolean function can be expressed as a sum of products of variables some of them being negated like for example $\displaystyle f(A,B,C)={\bar {A}}{\bar {B}}{\bar {C}}+{\bar {A}}B{\bar {C}}+A{\bar {B}}{\bar {C}}+ABC$ ?

Comment: Could you give the precise title and author of the book you mention ?

Comment: Sry. the title of the book is "ANALYSIS OF BOOLEAN FUNCTIONS", and its author is Ryan O’Donnell

Comment: The reason why I ask the question is that I need to construct a multilinear function based on a polynomial function, but feel confused about how to do it.The Book I mentioned before is a reference I just found and havn't read it carefully, but I think it may be a direction of thinking. And I also want to know it there any other theorem about the question because my math knowledge...you know .. I think it's not enough.

Comment: I learnt "Fourier expansion" in the course about signal processing.Obviously the form of "Fourier expansion" in this book is not the same with what I learnt.

Answer (score 0):

You understood the question posed in the image wrongly. It is ill-posed in your title.

I think that it is an application of a general result in Fourier theory: On every Hilbert space of functions, you can (1) write every function uniquely (2) as a fourier expansion. (with respect to a given orthonormal basis. Note that such a basis exists in every vector space if you assume the Axiom of Choice and apply the Gram-Schmidt process)

Comment: I don't believe that with a **finite** number of **discrete** variables (in {−1,1}), Hilbert space is the good framework. I think that the term "Fourier" isn't to be taken in its classical sense.